# Content popup box called by href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I use Wordpress and I would like to have a plugin that allow me to open a box/popup content for "a href" call.
Something like this:
`<a href="onclik open popup">Text</a>` use it in a div tag

this is the code i use:

```
<div class="tracklist download-button2" style="display: initial-block">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="header-clip2">
            <span class="header-triangle2"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="header-bg2"></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="file-icon-inner2">
            <i class="icon-download2"></i>Tracklist
        </div>
    </div>
```

please check http://af-sound.ro "Tracklist" button
so whoever will click on Tracklist, i would like to have a box popup opened with the content inside.

There will be more "tracklist" buttons, so i dont need just a global popup box. I have tried with Anything popup but that doesn't work as it use a shortcode like: [anythingpupup=id1] which cannot be used in "a href" call

Answer (score 0):

The first issue here is that you are missing the closing anchor tag

Secondly, you should give the box which you'd like to open an "id" attribute.

```
<div id="popup-box"></div>
```

Wherever you place your anchor tag, you can then reference the box using

```
<a href="#popup-box">Click to open popup</a>
```

The "#" will refer to the id attribute of the matched element.

There is no need to install an entire Wordpress plugin. You can use something like [Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

The instructions are very straight forward to help you set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a plugin for that. You could use just javascript to open such popup from an anchor. Here is an example code:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="Popup();"> Open Popup! </a>        
    <script language="javascript">
        function Popup()
        {
            var win = window.open('', '',"toolbar=no, width=100, height=20");
            var doc = win.document.open();
            doc.write('<html><body> <b>Hello!</b> </body></html>');
            doc.close();
        }
    </script>
```

As you can see, you can add any dynamic html as content of the popup, including the html that you want in the doc.write method.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways of achieving this, depending on the result you want to get.

Maybe the simplest way is not using a plugin at all; just add a hidden div with the content of the popup in it. And then, from jQuery, capture the click of your tag a and show up that hidden div. From CSS you can style that div in any way you need.

If you want to use a plugin, you could use [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) or any other similar, given the fact that you already have jQuery on your website.